# Filtering out strings in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I have the below query.

```
index=myindex sourcetype="application:access:log" host=myservers* FullURL="*/ABC"
```

It works. However, I'd like the output to show all URLs with ABC within them, I just don't want results with ABCD to show in them.

Any idea how I can get that done? I've tried the below but it's failing.

```
index=myindex sourcetype="application:access:log" host=myservers* FullURL="*/ABC" AND FullURL!="*ABCD*"
```

```
index=myindex sourcetype="application:access:log" host=myservers* FullURL="*/ABC" AND NOT FullURL="*ABCD*"
```

Comment: what is "failing", exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This query might do the trick :

```
index=myindex sourcetype="application:access:log" host=myservers* FullURL="*/ABC" | where NOT LIKE (FullURL="%ABCD%")
```